# Not able to run terraform from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I am trying to run a terraform command from jenkins pipeline but I am getting an error stating that, "terraform command not found". I have installed terraform plugins as well as terraform in the system where jenkins is also installed. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ This website is more about correcting code that has already been written and which may have issues that you're seeking help with _ You might be better consulting "terraform plugin" documentation for the information that you're seeking _ Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' for more details on writing questions >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Jenkins' Terraform plugin yet but have you considered to run inside a docker container which has preinstalled terraform?